# Android left side swipe menu with Toggle button

Tags: java, android, button, toggle

i'm trying to implement a toggle button with my side swipe menu but it isn't working I"m using tabhost and android.support.v4 widget.drawerlayout.

Don't really know where to start...

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <AnalogClock
                android:id="@+id/circles"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.learning.Activities.MapsActivity" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated

Comment: You can start a new project of type **New Drawer Activity** in android studio, it is simply implemented and will let you understand the basics of Left Side menu with toggle button

Comment: I had done that already, its just that I don't know how to add a "switch" button inside the actual **Navigational Drawer**.. any ideas?

Comment: Try building a custom drawer like in this link: [http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)

I started mine from here too.

Comment: Thats cool mate, followed the guide and that worked! I can add switches into the actual side menu now. Anyway to actually make it only on particular list as opposed to everything??

Comment: good to hear that, but i didn't get your question! sorry can you clarify please?

Comment: please check the bottom post

Comment: But you were saying, you don't know where to start and i directed you to a semi solution, anyway guy hope you find the good solution

Answer (score 0):

@HawraaKalil **Sorry I re-read and it isn't clear to me anymore haha so I see where you have gotten confused as well. What I was asking for was i could add the "Switch" to the side menu to replace the "Spinner" area from that Tutorial. But every time I try to use the actual side menu it crashes.**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--<Spinner-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/drawerSpinner"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="1" />-->
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchBitches"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bitches" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawerTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="#DADADC"></View>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

                />
        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#DADADC"></View>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`
```